# How do I Mute The Audio In Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, mute

with script this. what is wrong in script this ?

audio.mute = ToggleButton.isSpeakerOff;

sorry bad english,fast answer please
correct my script please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply google it, the following is from: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/52109/how-do-i-mute-all-audio-sound.html

AudioListener.pause = true;

AudioListener.volume = 0;

try this
http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/AudioListener-pause.html

Comment: AudioListener.pause = ToggleButton.isSpeakerOff;